# Como recorrer un json en jquery o javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"producto": [{"precio": 8000.0, "cantidad": 1, "venta_id": 23, "producto__nombreProducto": "Aguila ligth"}, 
{"precio": 50000.0, "cantidad": 1, "venta_id": 23, "producto__nombreProducto": "Ron medell\u00edn media"}, 
{"precio": 8000.0, "cantidad": 1, "venta_id": 23, "producto__nombreProducto": "Reds"}]}
```

como hago para recorrerlo

```
function verDetalle(ruta) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ruta,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            var salida = "";
            // salida = "<table class='table table-dark'>";
            for (const i in respuesta) {
                for (const j in respuesta[i]) {
                    salida += respuesta[i][j];
                }
            }
            // $.each(respuesta, function(indice, valor) {
            // salida += " <tr> <td> " + indice + "</td><td>" + valor + "</td></tr>"
            // });
            //salida += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("cuerpoModal").innerHTML = salida;

        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }

    });
}
```

eta intentando de esta manera pero no me da

Comment: Podrías comentarnos si te da algún error y cual es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres por ejemplo imprimir el precio de cada producto, puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var respuesta = {"producto": [{"precio": 8000.0, "cantidad": 1, "venta_id": 23, "producto__nombreProducto": "Aguila ligth"}, 
{"precio": 50000.0, "cantidad": 1, "venta_id": 23, "producto__nombreProducto": "Ron medell\u00edn media"}, 
{"precio": 8000.0, "cantidad": 1, "venta_id": 23, "producto__nombreProducto": "Reds"}]}



            var salida = "";
            // salida = "<table class='table table-dark'>";
            for (const i in respuesta.producto) {
                
                    salida += respuesta.producto[i].precio + ' ';
                
            }
            // $.each(respuesta, function(indice, valor) {
            // salida += " <tr> <td> " + indice + "</td><td>" + valor + "</td></tr>"
            // });
            //salida += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("cuerpoModal").innerHTML = salida;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cuerpoModal"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tu respuesta fue de gran ayuda